# Have the Modal show

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, dreamweaver

My modal only needs to show once when you open the browser page, not pop up every time you go back to that page.
When you close the website and open it up again, it has to display again.....

```js
let current_location = window.location.pathname;

let session_variable = sessionStorage.getItem(current_location);

if(session_variable) {
    console.log("Exists");
} else {
    console.log("Empty");
    sessionStorage.setItem(current_location, "Modal");
}
```

Comment: You mean it has to appear only once per user or appear every time the user comes?

Comment: So what happens now with your code you showed?  Does it never work? Sometimes work?  Works first time? Please [edit] your question to add that information.